# Batch file in right click menu 

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-registry, batch-file

I'm making a batch file that is going to encrypt information. I made it so when I right click on the object and click on the "test" button it runs the batch file.

In `regedit` I added

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Test\command
```

command's data is

```
C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\encrypt.bat
```

What do I need to do to the data (in the registry key i added) and what is it stored as in my variable?

Comment: The last sentence does not make sense to me. What do you mean by "what do I need to do to the data"?

Comment: I don't know about adding a selection to the right click shell menu, but if you go to `Start, Run -> shell:sendto`, you can add a shortcut or batch script and it will show up on a right click -> Send To. Also, if you use a batch script, the file name will be in %0, and full name (path + filename) will be in %1.

Comment: Okay were getting there but I need to know what variable would be the text. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate to the filetype the script you want to launch on that type. On Windows, all this is based on the extension (at least on XP, I don't know about 7, but I doubt it has changed).
Say the extension of your files are ".abc", and your app is:

```
c:\program files\dummy\process.bat
```

(I dropped the variable for the moment, I'm not sure how this behaves in .reg files)

So just edit a config.reg text file that will hold the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; the extension .abc gets associated with a file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc]
@="abc-file"

; the file-type gets a name (that appears in explorer in field "type")
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc-file]
@="foo file"

; What will appear in the contextual menu when selecting an .abc file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc-file\shell\cmdname-1]
@="--- Process ! ----"

; What to do with it
; here, %1 is the file given as argument of the script
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc-file\shell\cmdname-1\command]
@="\"c:\\program files\\dummy\\process.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Finally import it. You're done.

Additional comments:

- All the strange quotes and backslashes are there to allow correct handling of names with spaces. Yes, I now, nobody has spaces in file names.. Or do they ? Anyway, that happens!
- You can of course have several commands for a file type. Just dupe the last two keys of the .reg (cmdname-1 ==> cmdname-2)
- You can also associate different file extensions to the same file type. for example, HTML files can have either .htm or .html
- You can even associate an action to folders. replace the file type by "folder"
- It can be useful to provide a "uninstall" functionality. Just create another reg file and prefixe the created keys with '-'.